# Simple Forward Rate

Tags: forward-rate

I don't understand how can I conclude that F(t, T0, T1) < L(t, T1) < L(t, T0) base on the given answer.

[image]

Comment: The Correct solution contains a proof. What exactly there is not clear ? Intuitively, the spot rate for the longer period $L(t,T_1)$ is an *average* of $L(t,T_0)$ and the forward rate for the adjacent period.

Comment: Last two lines of the proof. Where do they come from ? What exactly P(t, T0)L(t, T1) means ? and how the proof relates to the answer ? Thanks.

Comment: $P(t,T)$ is a common notation for a discount factor. Somewhere in that reference where that question is from they must define this. If you find that out the rest is staightforward.  I find the question how the proof relates to the answer unbelievable. Please consider what exactly that proof shows by looking the most left hand side and the most right hand side of the chain of equations/inequalities.

Comment: One thing is probably worth thinking about: The proof uses the definition $P(t,T_0)=\frac{1}{1+(T_0-t)L(t.T_0)}$ and claims that $P(t,T_0)<1$ . Question: in the recent interest rate environment, can we say that this claim is always true ?

Comment: According to the previous lecture notes, (,) is the price at time t of a zero-coupon bond with maturity T. How can we conclude that the third line is greater than the second line of thr proof ? Why should we use the (,0)L(,1) to compare the second line of the proof ?

Comment: As for your question, inorder to make (,0) < 1, the sum of 1+(0−)(.0) must be  greater than 1. If t=T0, than (0−) is 0 and (,0) will 1. If t != T0 and less than T0, than L(t, T0) needs to be negative to make P(t, T0) to be greater than 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Too long for a comment.***

To answer the outstanding question of yours in the comment why the third line is greater than the second line:

Apparently the source of this exercise assumes $t<T_0<T_1$ and $0\color{red}{<}L(t,T_1)<L(t,T_0)$. The red $\color{red}<$-sign they assume without mentioning it. Then
\begin{align}
&F(t,T_0,T_1)\\&=\frac{1}{T_1-T_0}\Big(\frac{P(t,T_0)}{P(t,T_1)}-1\Big)\\
&=\frac{1}{T_1-T_0}\Bigg(\frac{1-(T_1-t)L(t,T_1)}{1-(T_0-t)L(t,T_0)}-1\Bigg)\\
&=\frac{1}{1-(T_0-t)L(t,T_0)}\frac{L(t,T_1)(T_1-t)-L(t,T_0)(T_0-t)}{T_1-T_0}\\[3mm]\tag{2nd line}
&=P(t,T_0)\frac{L(t,T_1)(T_1-t)-L(t,T_0)(T_0-t)}{T_1-T_0}\\[3mm]
&=\underbrace{P(t,T_0)\frac{L(t,T_1)(T_1-t)}{T_1-T_0}}_{(*)}-\underbrace{P(t,T_0)\frac{L(t,T_0)(T_0-t)}{T_1-T_0}}_{(**)}.
\end{align}
Because $L(t,T_0)(T_0-t)>0$ the term ($**$) is ***strictly greater than zero***. Dropping this term we see that the (2nd line) is ***less*** than
$$\tag{$*$}
P(t,T_0)\frac{L(t,T_1)(T_1-t)}{T_1-T_0}.
$$
In turn, since $t<T_0$, we have $\frac{T_1-t}{T_1-T_0}<1$ so that ($*$) is ***less*** than
$$\tag{3rd line}
P(t,T_0)L(t,T_1)\,.
$$
Together we have
$$
P(t,T_0)\frac{L(t,T_1)(T_1-t)-L(t,T_0)(T_0-t)}{T_1-T_0}<P(t,T_0)L(t,T_1)\,.
$$
$$\tag*{$\Box$}
\quad
$$

Comment: The assumptions make sense. However, it doesn't mean the third line is greater than the second line of the proof even if (,0)(0−) > 0 since we cannot determine if (,0)(0−) is greater or smaller than (,1)(1−).

Comment: Updated (to make it clearer what was there before). Please tell me where exactly I am wrong in your opinion.

Comment: This is very clear. I understand what you meant now. Thank you!